# Minimal SSD size for Xamarin build agent on a Mac

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm developer working on windows computer. I will start my first Xamarin.Forms project using Visual Studio 2017 on my windows PC. Since the target platform are IPhones, I'll need a new Mac solely as a Xamarin build agent. I never had a Mac before...

**Will a 128 GB SSD have enough space** to host the essential tools like the build agent, XCode and perhaps Visual Studio for Mac (if I decide to switch later on)?

I intend to keep my Windows computer for all other work, so the Mac is just for building and running the simulator.

In your experience, **will 8 GB of RAM be enough** - or will it slow down the build time considerably (it's a small project, perhaps 4-8 weeks of work, 1 person).

Answer (score 0):

It is ok as you have mentioned it is a small project for 3-4 weeks of duration. It would be better if you buy 256 GB SSD. Also another idea would be buying Mac mini. Mac mini is a device, in which you can get good configuration for better rate. You can connect Mac mini to any LED monitor and you can work. you can find [more details about it here](https://www.apple.com/ae/mac-mini/?afid=p238%7CsDUIVdRQi-dc_mtid_uwvume7rh0_pcrid_309632118955_&cid=wwa-ae-kwgo-mac-slid----%20mac%20%20mini-b)